# Invalid Markup Duplicate Attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving the following error in Dreamweaver CS6:  "Invalid Markup, Duplicate Attribute".  I have an image that onClick runs a function and swaps an image as well.  It's doing both, however Dreamweaver is squawking.  Does this have to be written another way?

```
<input type="image" onClick="javascript:displayPlace()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage ('Search','','SearchByPlace.jpg',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" src="Glass- Place.jpg"src="Glass-Place.jpg" alt="Place" align="middle" width="160" height="151">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `src="Glass- Place.jpg"src="Glass-Place.jpg"`, so `src` is in there twice.

Also, the values are different (extra space in the first one).

Comment: And only the one without a space is a conforming URL. There’s also the syntax error of not having whitespace between the two attribute specifications, but it of course vanishes when one of them is removed.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Time for a break!  It is now working properly!